# How to resolve the problems upgrade version of api application

Tags: java, api

I have a problem when deploy api to server.
when api has run on production enviroment(version1). we need to change some business. After test finished then we need deploy to server and run pilot(version2).
But client application we can't change and production enviroment has only one.
If we update driect and replace version1 then i can get dangerous.
So, i think you understand me, and please advise me some solutions for this problem
Thanks so much :)

Comment: Personally speaking, I didn't really get your problem. Could you please paraphrase the question and draw some simple deploymnet diagram?

Comment: Sounds like you need to set up a parallel test (pilot) server and client.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc yes, that's true. I need to parallel Pilot and Production